# Webauthn: Access control for the public key credential uploaded by the user's device

Tags: webauthn

I'm experimenting with adding passkeys to Drupal.

I'm using [webauthn-lib 4.7](https://webauthn-doc.spomky-labs.com).

When registering a passkey, the device generates a Public Key Credential, which is then sent to the server as stringified JSON:

```
{
  "publicKeyCredentialId": "example",
  "type": "public-key",
  "transports": [
    "internal",
    "hybrid"
  ],
  "attestationType": "none",
  "trustPath": {
    "type": "Webauthn\\TrustPath\\EmptyTrustPath"
  },
  "aaguid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "credentialPublicKey": "example",
  "userHandle": "example",
  "counter": 0,
  "otherUI": null
}
```

I save this data in a JSON field for authentication.

This JSON field is only accessible to the site administrator and the user who uploaded the credential.

**Does this public key credential need any additional protection?** Should I restrict users from viewing the data in this field?  It seems to only be the public key and userHandle, and the user's device uploaded the data in question, so I do not think I need any additional access control, but I want to ask here to be sure.

Comment: This is too much information and shouldn't be exposed to anyone. Instead have a "credential_name" field / id and only this info should be visible to users / admin in case they want to change the name or delete it.